# Display content- click button within the same php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have successfully managed to read files via php from a directory and dynamically create a drop down menu where I can see the content of the files. However, I did this via calling another php page. Is there a way to display the content of the text files within the same page? I know that this can be achieved by Ajax but I can't find any examples.

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateIframe(id,path) 
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    ifrm.src = "download.php?path="+path;
}
</script>
<body>
<?php
    //"file_to_be_displayed" is the name of the dropdown
    $selectedfile = @$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
    $path ="$selectedfile";
    $content = file($selectedfile);
    $data = implode("<br>",$content);
    echo $data;
?>
<?php
$dirname = "<path>";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form name="displayfile" action="print_output_file.php" method="POST" target="_blank">';
echo '<select name="file_to_be_displayed">';
echo '<option value="">Select File</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
         if(($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))             
        {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
        }
        }
                echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="display content of file"/>';
echo '</form>';
?>
</head>
</form>
<iframe id="frame1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:populateIframe('frame1','<?php echo $path; ?>')">download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

print_output_file.php function

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$myFile =$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
$myFile1 ="http://<file path>/"."$myFile";
$lines = file("$myFile1");
$fileString = file_get_contents("$myFile1");
echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($fileString) );
echo '<br>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

download.php function

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['path']);
readfile($_GET['path']);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does 'download.php' work? Did you search for AJAX?

Comment: Hi @putvande 
The download.php is not working yet but I am not concerned about it at the moment. I have searched for AJAX and found few examples online but not sure how to use the `$myFile` variable from php in order to instruct AJAX to display the specific file

Answer (score 1):

```
$dirname = "<path>";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form  action="" method="" target="">';
echo '<select id="select_file">';
echo '<option value="">Select File</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
         if(($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))             
        {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
        }
        }
                echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
```

JS

```
('#select_file').on('change', function() {
   var file_to_be_displayed = 'file_to_be_displayed='+$(this).val();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "print_output_file.php",
    data:file_to_be_displayed,
    success:function(data){
        $('#id_where_to_show').html(data);  
    }
    });
});
```

PHP FILE_TO_BE DISPLAYED // basically the same

```
<?php 
$myFile =$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
$myFile1 ="http://<file path>/"."$myFile";
$lines = file("$myFile1");
$fileString = file_get_contents("$myFile1");
echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($fileString) );
?>
```

So when you will select an option, it will load in  your file.

I hope, I correct understood what you wanted.. So no Iframe and $_GET[],

First output filenames as option in dropdown, on select pass file to ajax and it will return the content. YOu can play around for more...

Comment: Hi @Froxz the frame and Get was for the download function which is not working at the moment. I have tried the above solution but it doesn't work when I select the file. I would like to still have the button and once I click on it then the javascript script should display the relevant content

Comment: What error You have??? And why it is not working?
Try to Play with `('#select_file').on('change', function() {` Maybe I missed something...

Comment: There is no specific error. Once I select the file nothing happens.I've inserted the code like this:
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ('#select_file').on('change', function() {
       var file_to_be_displayed = 'file_to_be_displayed='+$(this).val();
       $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "print_output_file.php",
        data:file_to_be_displayed,
        success:function(data){
            $('#id_where_to_show').html(data);  
        }
        });
    }); 
    </script>

Comment: $('#id_where_to_show').html(data)

#id_where_to_show - it is div where the response will be shown so u need to create it... or make a different div with different id and specify it in ajax function.

Comment: Hi @Froxz div is already defined within the code as `<div id="id_where_to_show"></div>` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: using the chrome web development kit I get notified about an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #select_file has no method 'on'".